# How to create a help button within a dialog using wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Is it possible to create a help button that sends user to a web page (just like in MS Word, see below)? `wx.Dialog`'s `wx.DIALOG_EX_CONTEXTHELP` flag puts a query button on the caption, but it makes Windows go into a context-sensitive help that I don't need. It'd be great if this button just generated some event when pressed.

[image: Microsoft Word's paragraph settings]

Comment: why not create an actual button with wxID_HELP and handle clicks appropriately?

Comment: @Igor Could you provide more detailed explanation? I'd like to have the exactly same button on the caption but without entering context-sensitive mode

Comment: if you want a button on the caption than this is not possible. That's how context help works on any platform. You can have a workaround by creating a normal button inside the dialog. But this one shown will not operate like this. You don't have access to this button - it is created by the underlying OS and you just cant assign the event to it to do what you want.

Comment: @Igor But it somehow works in the case of the same MS Word

Comment: you need to draw to non-client area, which is quite bit of work. Check https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_window_d_c.html

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the button created by `wxWS_EX_CONTEXTHELP` style doesn't generate a wx event, but it can still be handled using MSW-specific code. Unfortunately I don't think you can easily do it from Python. In C++ this can be done by overriding `MSWHandleMessage()` virtual function for `message==WM_SYSCOMMAND` and `wParam==SC_CONTEXTHELP`.